# Rush hour - Iterative Deepening

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have to solve the "rush hour puzzle" by iterative deepening algorithm. I have read a lot of topics here on stackoverflow and also on the internet. I think that I understand the iterative deepening algorithm. Basically you just go deeper into the tree and try to find the solution.

I figured that I need to create a graph or a tree from the puzzle, but I really don't have an idea how. Also, if I would have the tree, then how would I tell if something is a valid move or a final state?

There were answers that the nodes should be possible moves and the edges are between the nodes that can be reached in one move. I can imagine this, but somehow I'm getting trouble in see how this can be useful or better yet how can this solve the problem.

Please help me, I'm not asking for complete solution or code sample, I just need some easy explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason you need to use the deepening algorithm. Imagine you name each car A, B, C, D... The root node of your tree is the initial board state. Now, move car A. You go down one node in the tree. Move car A back. You are at the initial state, but you made two moves to get here, so you are two nodes down the tree. Repeat over and over. You will never hit a final state.

The root node of your tree is the initial board state. Given that node, add a child node to it for every possible valid move. So, each child node will be what the initial tree looks like after one move. Now, for each of those child nodes, do the same thing: make a child node where each node is one move off the original child node.

Eventually, you will hit a solution to the puzzle. When that happens, you print the moves from the root node to the solution child node and quit. This algorithm ensures that you find a solution with the least number of moves.

Comment: Thanks, so the node would actually represent the whole board? It make sense to me now. This is however very memory consuming, is there any other approach?

Comment: There are two methods. Method 1: Each node is an entire board (you'd make it an object, of course). Method 2: Each node is a move. To see the state of the board at a node, you must start with the initial board and go through the tree to get to the node you are checking since all you have are moves. One takes more memory. One takes more processing time. Which do you want to do?

Comment: I think i will go with more memory. The move method seems a bit complicated